# Models for classify Noun Phrase?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, hidden-markov-models

I need a model for the following tasks:

a sequence of words, with its POS tags. I want to judge whether this sequence of words is a Noun Phrase or not.

One model I can think of is HMM.

For those sequences which are noun phrase, we train a HMM (HMM+). For those are not noun phrase, we try an HMM(HMM-). And when we do prediction for a sequence, we can calculate P(sequence| HMM+) and P(sequence|HMM-). If the former is larger, we think this phrase is a noun phrase, otherwise it's not.

What do you think of it? and do you have any other models suited for this question?

Comment: Try it and see how it goes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My hunch is that an HMM is not the right model. It can be used to guess POS tags, by deriving the sequence of tags with the highest probabilities based on prior probabilities and conditional probabilities from one token to the next.

For a complete noun phrase I don't see how this model matches.

Any probability based approach will be very difficult to train, because noun phrases can contain many tokens. This makes for really many combinations. To get useful training probabilities, you need really huge training sets.

You might quickly and easily get a sufficiently good start by crafting a set of grammar rules, for example regular expressions, over POS tags by following the description in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase#Components_of_noun_phrases

or any other linguistic description of noun phrases.

Comment: Thanks, I decide to use Stanford Parser directly.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you already have POS tags for the sequence of words. Once you have tags for the sequence of words, you don't need to use HMM to classify if the sequence is a NP. All you need to do is look for patterns of the following forms:

1. determiner followed by noun
2. adjective followed by noun
3. determiner followed by adjective followed by noun

etc

As somebody just mentioned,HMMs are used to obtain POS tags for new sequence of words. But for that you need a tagged corpus to train the HMM. There are some tagged corpus available in NLTK software.

If your sequences are already tagged then just use grammar rules as mentioned in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

People do use HMMs to label noun phrases in POS-labeled sentences, but the typical model setup does not work in quite the way you're describing.

Instead, the setup (see [Chunk tagger-statistical recognition of noun phrases (PDF)](http://arxiv.org/abs/cmp-lg/9807007) and [Named entity recognition using an HMM-based chunk tagger (PDF)](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1073163) for examples) is to use an HMM with three states:

- O (not in an NP),
- B (beginning of an NP),
- I (in an NP, but not the beginning).

Each word in a sentence will be assigned one of the states by the HMM. As an example, the sentence:

> The/DT boy/NN hit/VT the/DT ball/NN with/PP the/DT red/ADJ bat/NN ./.

might be ideally labeled as follows:

> The/DT **B** boy/NN **I** hit/VT **O** the/DT **B** ball/NN **I** with/PP **O** the/DT **B** red/ADJ **I** bat/NN **I** ./. **O**

The transitions among these three HMM states can be limited based on prior knowledge of how the sequences will behave; in particular, you can only transition to I from B, but the other transitions are all possible with nonzero probability. You can then use Baum-Welch on a corpus of unlabeled text to train up your HMM (to identify any type of chunk at all -- see [Simple Unsupervised Grammar Induction from Raw Text with Cascaded Finite State Models (PDF)](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220873937_Simple_Unsupervised_Grammar_Induction_from_Raw_Text_with_Cascaded_Finite_State_Models/file/79e4150992f8e85b5b.pdf) for an example), or some sort of maximum-likelihood method with a corpus of labeled text (in case you're looking specifically for noun phrases).